# Code Review класс для длинной арифметики, архитектура и эффективность

Tags: c++

Прошу совет насчет улучшения качества моего кода (что-то вроде code-review), который я мог бы использовать при дальнейшей разработке.

Есть основа класса, представляющего 256-битный элемент конечного поля, и несколько функций для работы с ним:

`field.h`

```
#ifndef FIELD_H
#define FIELD_H

#include <cstdint>
#include <array>

/*
    Finite field GF(p)
    p = 2^255 - 19
    using 2^255 = 19 mod p
*/

namespace field
{

    class FieldElement
    {
        std::array<uint64_t, 5> chunks;

    public:
        FieldElement(std::array<uint64_t, 5> a);

        friend bool operator==(const FieldElement&, const FieldElement&);
        friend FieldElement operator+(const FieldElement&, const FieldElement&);
    };

    bool operator==(const FieldElement& lhs, const FieldElement& rhs);
    FieldElement operator+(const FieldElement& lhs, const FieldElement& rhs);

    FieldElement zero();
    FieldElement one();

    FieldElement reduce(std::array<uint64_t, 5>& a);
}

#endif
```

`field.cpp`

```
#include "field.h"

using field::FieldElement;

FieldElement::FieldElement(std::array<uint64_t, 5> a)
{
    chunks[0] = a[0];
    chunks[1] = a[1];
    chunks[2] = a[2];
    chunks[3] = a[3];
    chunks[4] = a[4];
}

namespace field
{
    bool operator==(const FieldElement& lhs, const FieldElement& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.chunks == rhs.chunks;
    }

    FieldElement operator+(const FieldElement& lhs, const FieldElement& rhs)
    {
        std::array<uint64_t, 5> r{0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            r[i] = lhs.chunks[i] + rhs.chunks[i];
        }
    }

    FieldElement zero()
    {
        return FieldElement({0, 0, 0, 0, 0});
    }

    FieldElement one()
    {
        return FieldElement({1, 0, 0, 0, 0});
    }

    FieldElement reduce(std::array<uint64_t, 5>& limbs)
    {
        const uint64_t LOW_51_BIT_MASK = (static_cast<uint64_t>(1) << 51) - 1;

        uint64_t carry0 = limbs[0] >> 51;
        uint64_t carry1 = limbs[1] >> 51;
        uint64_t carry2 = limbs[2] >> 51;
        uint64_t carry3 = limbs[3] >> 51;
        uint64_t carry4 = limbs[4] >> 51;

        limbs[0] &= LOW_51_BIT_MASK;
        limbs[1] &= LOW_51_BIT_MASK;
        limbs[2] &= LOW_51_BIT_MASK;
        limbs[3] &= LOW_51_BIT_MASK;
        limbs[4] &= LOW_51_BIT_MASK;

        limbs[0] += carry4 * 19;
        limbs[1] += carry0;
        limbs[2] += carry1;
        limbs[3] += carry2;
        limbs[4] += carry3;

        return FieldElement(limbs);
    }
}
```

Как можно улучшить этот код? У меня есть пока что несколько вопросов:

1) Как лучше сгруппировать этот код неймспейсами? Стоит ли что-то куда-то внести или вынести? Применить другой синтаксис?

2) Реализация операторов как friend. Можно ли сделать это лучше? При реализации операторов для длинных чисел нужно получать доступ к внутреннему представлению числа как вектора редуцированных коэффициентов.

3) Как улучшить конструирование объектов FieldElement? Сделать статический фабричный метод, который получает вектор коэффициентов и возвращает FieldElement? Или нет?

4) Можно ли применить constexpr-выражения для более эффективной реализации библиотеки?

Что еще можно придумать?

Comment: Вы хотите кросс-библиотеку или библиотеку для винды/линукса? Ассемблерными вставками можна используя sse2 или sse3 команды (или другие расширеные) более быстро делать сложение. Современные процессоры (для ПК) позволяют делать операции над такими большими числами. это добавит быстродействие.

Comment: 3) + Что еще можно придумать? Например, мув-конструкторы и мув-равно. Это может ускорить создание элементов. Вроде как ваш текущий конструктор принимает std::array<uint64_t, 5>, также можно изменить на константную ссылку, чтобы исключить паразитное копирование.

Comment: 2) friend - нужен для взаимодействия с "чужими" классами. Внутри одного класса этот термин отсутствует, т.к. класс уже дружествен по отношению сам к себе. К открытым елементам других классов доступится можно и без указания friend. И то, friend действует на предоставление доступа "*из*", а не "*к*", т.е. к закрытым елементам (например vector) доступ всёравно не получите.

Comment: Вместо копирования `std::array<uint64_t, 5>` можно было бы объявить алиас `using Chunks = std::array<uint64_t, 5>;` и в дальнейшем использовать его. В коде явно нехватает модификаторов `noexcept`, плюс многие из этих методов могут быть `constexpr`. `using field::FieldElement;` ни к чему, там ведь дальше все в неймспейсе идет.

Comment: 1) namespace нужен что бы классы не перемешивались между собой. это на ваше усмотрение нужен он или нет, и как называется. Если вы работаете в команде - согласовать с командой. Особо это на работоспособность не повлияет.

Comment: По поводу расширеных команд - тут [вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B_x86) их собрание

Comment: SSE не поддерживает 256-битные числа, их поддерживает [FMA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMA)

Comment: Сдвиг лучше сделать через ассемблерные rcl rcl - будет работать быстрее.

Comment: С точки зрения использования, было бы полезно: (1) добавить печать/чтение в стандартные потоки вывода, хотя бы для целей отладки. (Не забыть про атрибут hex.); (2) Расширить список операций (вычитание, битовые операции...). (3) Конструктор из uint64_t , чтобы можно было писать выражение  A+12;

Answer (score 1):

Вы явно недооцениваете оптимизатор. Можно писать более универсальный код без особых потерь . Думаю, будет полезно посмотреть, [во что компилируется код](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAViAIzkA2AhgHaioCkATAEK8%2B5AM7oArqVTYQAcl4BmAm1RMxOANRd5AYVTCihNkS24uABgCCCpSrXZNOlqVIsAnifNXLAegBUn9UD1ADElYnsAMwJsJkx1AHFgiAAHAEoAoOSHABF1Hi4AVlweAoL1AFp1egBODMCxYSVgPMLi0pyq6vUAWyx1ZM9fb09PNhZu7GFklil1KJjMEYB2AUs69RUWYWEQ6NjcJmwJo3WuFZHLIP6xACMmAlQQdauGpvVMFiIWAH0iV2T7FpcvpMCAQE4XO4dGIlEQAGwAFl%2B5HUBQ88j46m83k02TMXGq%2BLxXD4AmJfAAHFxyUT6FwKXTsnSKZjqfi%2BEs2STsly%2BLT6ZzyVSmfT8uS0eSycztLyeeTcLjmfJecFqcyiezTCKKbUaWr6VrmTxcey4bzhezBey5dLnkFsAAPZL3VDEXYLA5HbBGCAfL6/f72FjpDFYnFc6py9kS5mq8li628rXRk0kuPq3kSzW8xkZvXkq0k5MkhMkjXc82ZxX03OipOV7XG3mFvkq/UU8t8GN1oXtsXSzRrS5XIIRUjRNhxG7odBMdToAEuEikIFAiAYNj6d37Q7HYw8OEojdb0Ie3fe/dwkOrCwj0fj71xU87r1GeeLz5kQTr9CbojbzBPT3XhDw2X8Tz2QDzxOA9rwuW9MnHAA3T5pDtQI/R%2BP4AQ2JAxDYABrYQtBvK4zh5DF4KuadZ3fbAly/eQKOyH8/wAoCLxA9QmCQYQj3A/9nyg19L3UUheLg4dAiEji3wXejPxXfhWIgs8RK4ni%2BLAtiZOg0TxOESSvAQ6TINk/8AC96PQCAjKuXSRPnNhsFskiqKCBy9zE7BMDEKQIE8i8wUwgMcODEiw1TCx%2B3pZVG1TPg42jdtOyzEkEV5fkKRbMwEqSosEqjEk0r4Kx5VldtawpUtW3JG0e0TcryS6SrWu1Ml2Q6kkypTXkYo7dt8r4BEEq6ykEpq7sBrqzLlh5IcLFeDg5kgsFApOSiFvWog1rMvSAr2kTgs%2BLDA3UcK1nOKS5jICBYXUAgOnxUNHq0bRcPwoiADpGis1zQ0EQQCHSa6rlQPDCOIgo%2BAIQpciBc7ChhuGIuxVNqh6oteRlckhotEkpXpdMGqx7VcvbErDXpTsqYpfG%2BAVds4vZHHkvFPsEuLRK%2BwbFneZJFthTzbN41mxt23e9szV7clMdJdsb3I%2BCxgmKYZkiSDllIoIaLneSGJXJi12PQTDuAg9uN4/idLNziLYMkGTM0K6nauUhsCICQ2Et4QvvBz6dlXJixN4v2IaItzrqVhb7NtuSP2Xb8TfYvSNKt7TVJfc24RDwzThdu9AhBMEITcN6YSMRFkVRExvOMTbXdHMh1Dut9XuD57MXb960QB/ggcdwvne1ofAnd4xodhgp4eDzSw4DpGp/h/hc/nyHF5Rhuh%2Bjxux49r2U/UlZx6V0M0a5aKmY5vqFYS%2BmWyK2rmRy3lCYpVmK3lBKX/JKqxrf1kot2ZkwqtqOKRoJbf1AeyLKLYSqP3pmiKOSx5rGVjmpLyVlSA2UHkEM4I8RzjwPttfB21jr%2BmwtgfBSsUGo3DMSSMV9JSDWxuaBKH8n41jauyemTZtSMhgdjKB%2BZ2RDS5mNeqFIhpTX6lVVUyDUHrG2k5FyuDAjUNBkEIhpBvYkPOCsOktDaFn3ofiS%2BYDr4zWASLdkGUrE2IFtAss7YH5JmrAydxNVaYtjlhSYRwtipOMpINdxgseYiJJAIwJzDtQcMfrTKqNUKRfXRvEvKbi2oQIiXwR%2BdjBEgPFmAwqmYmHsjlp2H%2BjVGrMjGmUFxr8SlWJqewsWzIqpROCUAmBd8glC3pNLHhYtOr8w5A2PMSp2y01kSEtsX9Skkg4eI%2Bp2SEGTJbqAiZMTYysKFKkQcTsd5KLjv%2Bd2vl/JkJACFSh3ECDdBuHnZBBCwYCUdMkUg6gK7wiRP%2BAAMgAeQAOrfAKPQb4fAACSAAVb4ABZCwABlAA0h0CAnyq5EAgPQPZb03qoixRUKokdd7nTECQOY2CjDfFQBCVwKL7h3N9jcGYBFbIOFMPIBUILUi%2BBqESoeERbrFxAL9bAvwHodHpfcn6BA/p7MqHSF6bKEYKsxOUcowN8H7NHkEFgpL0AbBpRK259zF7lDpNPJVHK8V8u1TchlG8LUgQRv8oFIKwVQthQixFNrtWSqhsjR1/dg7UucFCJ5eDaGaMCH6pG%2BJA0CGDmOX8RAqU0p9YQ/eOjD7ARWDG4xBDDkoJkKkZgsgCgyHIGwWQZgK3oFkDKfuK9RASFmAoegFadoyBrakEtBEQAgq%2BvIHg8h6A8BKPQegCJsoFCWKWmQCIK3dH7WYSt1ba2yArcIEAK7O3dvIHAWAKAMA4HwMQMglBqB0B4MwdgnBAb8BEOISQ0g5DDpsKoDQb09AGFhB4NYb7lAfsBI4ZwZcOXwT8Ectg4QVoLASEkNI6wsgI3yEUEoZR5W1GuktZoqG2h1ODjUHofQBiWCGMrcYkxpizHmLELW7lAibG2Nmzijz0LqCFaXKE2g0XfJRL3BU/t14NyQ7cF0Two0sZ9Jx0D3HePVwE%2BdIy7GxwTinDOPWCdGLMRUqbDBdtQLJxIbBdNVxVOPik/%2BfWikk4CUsyBa2mdhLZzshGiiitrq6zogbIOLEjPHLTlpfz%2BmYI5wdum5R1nE7KWC1nAzPtHN6bi6F3OynrrKKwTgiLxyVH/Q807ZRpy/IuRk5CcusJ0X8druFETkbjI4dg7EXaIX675YudtCApWwM8Yq3xmuVqLpWALkEITEdoZxpnrkFgsbN4ENG/681k3EbQ0W%2Bm%2BbSNUNLem9DTba3w7%2BuVI64O22%2BCHfc%2Bsdb0MMpHam0ja753LqKMsCrKj6tGuLEugQrzUXtPGzs8ZnOmlEv2fthJfO4a96eyzXPebOQEYGTXhHLebmGOWe8zZmL/2AsWyBxnJLzn4vhbY5JrrcnesKdriuFYK71A07pyifE%2BaVPN1bv%2BduuRO7itxb3VkjaYZqJHBo4lbsHVLZh/t0XmgV4I8uwGh7xKd5D20d7Q2Ba6tHJa%2BoTLrlifEuV5ZiA%2BD6e04Zwz8irn1Hq/Szl38qjwfsf1x1/BjATeu7p%2Bb9Nhzrea6K/5Un5XK59cU36gXQuh7J3k78wFwLQUQuhXCpFKL9CfAeKm/QAevm/BMJi7FOhuf4vlUS9jkeDWhvJrPY1/qJuWs5Sq4v5P/whtIK4egRr7UrbhjX61yO7wl6b64JsFf298E213kFpmgh95pfINvJroZnbH3XyTU/Q0jQRjGq7nf0S16L5JjfrZA1mmDi6mP7r49eon9GyvSNFtS6P7kE/bq4%2BeqRZfu1c%2BR9b4PM66PT%2BPUJ%2B9R7xHH3wXydWP1/1j3/wvyAKuH33uzvx/1dUgPP1fxEz32v3Gy/wTVyH7xGl8E6Df331v0BmDRpU7nY331HxIJwJpSX2JRAKwIRn73yBgKCDgMYNINDWVDQL10zV0WOQgBD093VyLRLSYDLQrSrS7XXRkAbQECbSfVbWHR4A7TXR7XICQGwBYBwFIGoDENkAXXICXQKBXSkJrXIDrRkE3W3XIF3WLV7X7XoEHWHVHXHUnWnVnXEJkHkEkLXQsI3VsLUP3UQAPWQDQHQG6GSAIEOAoCoB/EiOiPohAGACWHkHICiCYCIHoi3QgBuD8JuCUCcFcFkHbXIAwG6D3D%2BTYCYGKOkPIBwG6FvUOD8MIHdlQCIAICQkmD8MdGwFQFJRfVKNhBiD8KIHHCXWkLENvTQHvSEHuHuXgBLQXA6PAlkHKBBCBG4D53oCWAqD%2BR8MfRbWkCxTnXLVXTqMsIdApDhHKERHUGAFQFQHUCWEHRblPWXClxHRRG0AiKiJiM%2BJ4D2TkMEFUMmIcKnS%2BjhCWDhGyiWCnQpBBR4ARAREPC8MMOMNML8MsOsJ3SCNCIgCPV%2BMSNiOoHKL%2BKSJSLSIyKyNIByLyLqIKLGGbxKIrXKMqOqNqPMIaKaJfS5IIDaI6K6K3TqN6P6KyJZMoCMBGLqLGNuSCNYA4BmL52YAIAWMgCWOSBWM3DWI2KYi2PkL4B2L2IOObWfRAEBNON8IuNkCuJuLuIeKeJeJnwgHeObgUGvXUB%2BISP%2BLbSBNmNBO7RLU0O0KSNsjnXROXXOPMOxJEBsLsPUL7QhKhJhKWDhLpkRORNRNkAOLMJkIDPsLnRUKjLzMCLBPIC6NpIIF/BAARCAA) (сверху - измененная реализация). Различия, конечно, есть - но еще не известно, какой вариант быстрее. Да и более общая реализвация позволяет переделать класс в шаблонный, если вдруг понадобится.

Далее, `std::array` - это реализация. Для интерфейса больше подойдет `std::initializer_list` - всё-равно он неявно преобразуется в массив, а так не нужно писать лишние {}. Или можно сделать шаблонный констуктор, принимающий всё, из чего можно создать массив. Я бы на вашем месте конструировал объект из `std::initializer_list` без всяких фабрик, а нужные операции над самим массивом реализовывал через дружественные и статические функции. Те же `zero` и `one` вполне можно сделать статическими функциями. Но это всё дело вкуса и контекста. Для решения конкретной прикладной задачи особо мудрить с интерфейсом обычно смысла нет, но для библиотечного класса стоит уделить ему повышенное внимание.

`constexpr`-выражения однозначно можно использовать - там все функции можно сделать `constexpr`. Только `reduce` нельзя, но я сомневаюсь, что вы действительно хотите передавать аргумент по неконстантной ссылке. Но если захотите использовать ассемблерные вставки - с `constexpr` придётся попрощаться, в C++ нет возможности писать разные реализации для константных и неконстантных выражений.

Упомянутые в комментариях move-констукторы в данном случае точно не нужны, т.к. перемещение не будет быстрее копирования.